# Make radio button `checked` in a recursive function

Tags: php, radio-button, checked

I am using this recursive function to display a list with radio buttons.

```
function displayList(&$cats, $parent, $level=0) {
    switch ($level) {
        case 0: $class = "list-unstyled categorychecklist"; break;
        case 1: $class = "children"; break;
        case 2: $class = "children2"; break;
    }
    if ($parent==0) {
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
            displayList($cats, $id);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<ul class='$class'>\n";
        foreach ($cats[$parent] as $id=>$nm) {
            echo "<li><input type='radio' value='$id' name='category'> $nm</li>\n";
            if (isset($cats[$id])) {
                displayList($cats, $id, $level+1);  //increment level
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }  
}
```

My question is, How I add `checked` attribute for radio buttons using this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `checked` HTML attribute to your item by replacing

```
echo "<li><input type='radio' value='$id' name='category'> $nm</li>\n";
```

with

```
echo "<li><input type='radio' value='$id' name='category' checked> $nm</li>\n";
```

Note that only one `radio` within a radio group should be checked.

Comment: yes it can be done. But I need to display `checked` attribute if only my `$_POST array true.

Comment: @user3733831 You didn't mention it in the question. So, just wrap it with your `if` condition.

Comment: Can you kindly tell me how to edit `IF` conditon? Thank you

Comment: @user3733831 What do you mean by "`$_POST` array true"? Actually, at StackOveflow people help with solving problems. I can't help you with a trivial `if` condition, you should try to do it yourself.